# Fill non-consecutive blanks in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is pretty naive, but I would appreciate any help.
So I have the following situation like here below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 1 |
|  | 2 |
| 0.5 | 3 |
| 0.5 | 4 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| 0.5 |  |
|  |  |

I need to copy the four values in column B into the empty cells in column A, so that A2 gets B1, A5 gets B2, A6 gets B3, and so on. Is there any formula that does the trick?
Thanks.

I already tried the formula

`= if(A2="",B1,"0.5")`

but this is not what I need, as it does not take the entries in B column consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the results to be in Column A:

- Duplicate Column A someplace else

  - I used Column H

Then use this formula:

```
A1: =IF(H1="",INDEX($B:$B,COUNTBLANK($H$1:H1)),H1)
```

and fill down.

[image]

*If the results do not need to be in Column A, you can put that formula anyplace and just refer to column A instead of Column H.*

Or, you can use this single formula in some cell if you have `365`:

```
=LET(
    colA, $H$1:$H$8,
    colB, $B$1:$B$4,
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(colA),
        1,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            IF(
                CHOOSEROWS(colA, r) = "",
                CHOOSEROWS(
                    colB,
                    ROWS(
                        FILTER(
                            CHOOSEROWS(colA, SEQUENCE(r)),
                            CHOOSEROWS(colA, SEQUENCE(r)) = ""
                        )
                    )
                ),
                CHOOSEROWS(colA, r)
            )
        )
    )
)
```